# Shortcut launches incorrect activity in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I have experienced a problem in my application consisting of two main activities. Minimum (not) working example is an ActivityA, which in its onCreate method creates shortcut for the ActivityB.

When the ActivityB shortcut is then launched from homescreen, the ActivityB is launched and after that the ActivityA is launched too - totaly unexpectedly! However, this only happens when ActivityA is not destroyed. If you destroy the activity somehow (memory cleaning app or something like that) than it is not called.

I believe I am doing something terribly wrong in my application.

Here is ActivityA

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class ActivityA extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent shortcutintent = new Intent();
        shortcutintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "Shortcut");
        shortcutintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        shortcutintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ShortcutActivity.class));
        shortcutintent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
        sendBroadcast(shortcutintent);
    }
}
```

Here is ActivityB

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ActivityB extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Hey, I just started activity!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }
}
```

Here is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.test.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.test.ShortcutActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `android.intent.action.MAIN` for more than one activity in your manifest. If you want your application to perform different things after the first launch, I would advise saving a [shared preference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref). If the preference is not present, go ahead and create your shortcut. If it is present, go ahead and execute other code. Also, you should not call `finish()` in `onCreate()`. If you want to perform a task, why not just create another function or an `AsyncTask`? No need to launch and get rid of a whole `Activity`.

Comment: The reason why I am using the second activity is, because I want the second activity to perform a simple background operation _after hitting the shortcut_ - not much more complicated than the toast from my example. Is there any reason not to use two main activities? I mean - I thought this to be completely valid. In the original application I am creating the shortcut not in onCreate but after pushing a button, I just simplified the app. Also, I do not see how AsyncTask applies.